# function for filter data does not work after first use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, reducers

I'm building an app with React, and redux. The purpose of the following is to act as a reducer(attached with a combined Reducer) to the main. I'm importing a filterData function, **which works the first time you choose any Action type the first time**. Sadly, the filterData function will not after the first action. I think it's got to do with the fact, my first action filters all other data... and has nothing to work with. I need the filter data function to keep working after the user choose any action, and to keep passing the action.payload

```
import {
    FETCH_USERS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
    STATUS_5500_SUBMITTED_ActionType,
    STATUS_5500_Success_ActionType,
    STATUS_5500_Ready_To_File_ActionType,
    STATUS_5500_Error_ActionType,
    SortingAllPlansAlphabetically
} from "./FakeStuff/userTypes";


import { filterData } from "../../States/AllStates/FakeStuff/userActions";

const initialState = {
    loading: true,
    data: [],
    error: ""
};


const FakeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                //data: action.payload,
                data: filterData(action.payload),
                error: ""
            };
        case FETCH_USERS_FAILURE:
            return {
                loading: false,
                data: [],
                error: action.payload
            };


        case STATUS_5500_SUBMITTED_ActionType:
            return {
                data: filterData(state.data, "Submitted"),
            };

        case STATUS_5500_Success_ActionType:
            return {
                data: filterData(state.data, "Success")
            };


        case STATUS_5500_Ready_To_File_ActionType:
            return {
                data: filterData(state.data, "Ready To File")

            };
        case STATUS_5500_Error_ActionType:
            return {
                data: filterData(state.data, "Error")

            };

        case SortingAllPlansAlphabetically:
            return {
                loading: state.loading,
                error: state.error,
                data: console.log("yolo")
            };



        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default FakeReducer;
```

my Function from another file

```
export const filterData = (Data, searchText) => {
    console.log("filterData's searchText value is : " + searchText)
    return Data.filter(xyz => {

        if (xyz.Status55.includes(searchText)) {
            return true;

        }
        if (xyz.planType.includes(searchText)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (searchText === undefined) {
            return true;
        }

        if (searchText !== undefined) {
            return false;
        }

    })

}
```

I also have the following to load the initial data, and dispatch action after Axios sucesfully loaded stuff

```
export const fetchUsers = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersRequest)
        //axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        axios.get("./PublicData/BookOfBusiness.json")
            .then(response => {
                const users = response.data
                dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users))

            })
            .catch(error => {
                const ErrorMsg = error.message
                dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(ErrorMsg))
            })
    }
}
```

thank you for ANY HELP.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Does the function get called? Does it not give the expected result? Can you give an example of want you expect vs what you get? Glancing at your code and problem description it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: @James Hi, james, I've just updated the original post. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [selectors](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data/) to filter the data just before render. This way you keep the source data intact and just switch the `filter` state.

Reducers now set only the `filter` state:

```js
...

case STATUS_5500_SUBMITTED_ActionType:
  return {
    ...state,
    filter: "Submitted"
  };

case STATUS_5500_Success_ActionType:
  return {
    ...state,
    filter: "Success"
  };

...
```

And you can use a selector to map the state to props within the `connect` helper:

```
const filterData = ({ data, filter }) => {
  ...filter code goes here - it must return the filtered data
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: filterData(state)
})

const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

You can optimize the selectors by using `createSelector` helper from https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect so they are computed only when their arguments change (memoization/caching).

Comment: thank you, however It doesn't seem to work with the current logic. I'm trying to call the filterData as you recommended at the mapStateToProps. Still working on it, and I will update the finding.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the `state` you receive in `mapStateToProps` is the global redux state - you may need to extract your inner and desired state first.